# Why does String.prototype.match() return null instead of empty array?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example taken from [MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
var paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked.';
var regex = /[A-Z]/g;
var found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found); // will return an array of matches and returns null when nothing matches.
```

I would like to know the reasoning behind returning null instead of returning an Empty Array when nothing matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `String.prototype.match` is defined in the EcmaScript standard

1. [21.1.3.11String.prototype.match ( regexp )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.match)
2. [21.2.5.7RegExp.prototype [ @@match ] ( string )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-regexp.prototype-@@match)
3. [21.2.5.2.2Runtime Semantics: RegExpBuiltinExec ( R, S )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-regexpbuiltinexec)

In short: if nothing matches - it returns `null` by the standard.

Comment: If someone can comment on why this designed like this will be helpful. I understand this is how it is in docs but if there is a reason for null , would be helpful from learning perspective.

Comment: @RamKumar one benefit of not returning empty array is you need to not to check `[].length` to test whether it is `true or false` ,

Comment: @lazydev, I don't know whether you have solved this problem, but [here](https://codepen.io/loglinn05/pen/JjaqpEm) is the way you can return an empty array instead of `null`. Good luck!

Comment: What about the reason why `String.prototype.match()` returns `null`, I guess if it had returned an empty array the method would always have returned a truthy value (an empty array or object evaluate to `true`), so, as @CodeManiac said, we would have to check the length of the returned array to test whether `true` or `false` was returned.

Comment: @Angelina "we would have to check the length of the returned array" --- it really is not a problem to create a non-homogeneous typed function. `if (result)` vs `if (result.length)` is equally good (or bad).

Comment: @zerkms, I didn't say that it's a problem, I've just made some assumptions about the reason why the method returns `null` by the standard. The main thing I tried to say is if `match()` had returned an empty array, the method would always have returned a truthy value, and, honestly, I don't know what this could have led to.